# Who is the wonderful artist?

Tags: support, april-fools, time-machine, unicorns

Who is the ascii artist?

```
    <!--
                    HAPPY APRIL FOOL'S FROM STACK OVERFLOW

                  \/                    __/   .::::.-'-(/-/)
                         _/:  .::::.-' .-'\/\_`*******          __ (_))
            \/          /:  .::::./   -._-.  d\|               (_))_(__))
                         /: (""""/    '.  (__/||           (_))__(_))--(__))
                          \::).-'  -._  \/ \\/\|
                  __ _ .-'`)/  '-'. . '. |  (i_O
              .-'      \       -'      '\|
         _ _./      .-'|       '.  (    \\                         % % %
      .-'   :      '_  \         '-'\  /|/      @ @ @             % % % %
     /      )\_      '- )_________.-|_/^\      @ @ @@@           % %\/% %
     (   .-'   )-._-:  /        \(/\'-._ `.     @|@@@@            ..|........
      (   )  _//_/|:  /          `\()   `\_\     |/_@@             )'-._.-._.-
       ( (   \()^_/)_/             )/      \\    /                /   /
        )  _.-\\.\(_)__._.-'-.-'-.//_.-'-.-.)\-'/._              /
    .-.-.-'   _o\ \\\     '::'   (o_ '-.-' |__\'-.-;~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~~/   /\
              \ /  \\\__          )_\    .:::::::.-'\          '- - -|
         :::''':::::^)__\:::::::::::::::::'''''''-.  \                '- - -
        :::::::  '''''''''''   ''''''''''''':::. -'\  \     C. SWANSIGER
    _____':::::_____________________________________\__\______________________
    -->
```

Comment: `C. SWANSIGER` carries a hint?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ still interesting IMO, couldn't find anything except [this](https://www.asciiart.eu/mythology/unicorns) which still does not document where this originates from

Comment: Is the ascii art broken by purpose? (first line missing, second line moved to the right)

Comment: ASCII art aside: *EYES ... BLEEDING! MUST UNSEE!!1!*

Comment: It's obviously not ASCII but Unicorde.

Comment: Hmmm....reminds me of an MS paint picture I made recently of Personified SO riding a unicorn. I don't do ASCII (or Unicorde) art though.

Answer (score 29):

C. SWANSIGER was [an occasional poster on rec.arts.ascii](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/%22C.$20SWANSIGER%22%7Csort:relevance). The specific post this unicorn can be found in was titled [line: unicorn](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/rec.arts.ascii/y68KTAC_bYw/XDuDtSUfLAkJ):

```
_____________________________________________________________________________
                            ___________ _
  \/                    __/   .::::.-'-(/-/)
                     _/:  .::::.-' .-'\/\_`*******            __ (_))
        \/          /:  .::::./   -._-.  d\|                 (_))_(__))
                     /: (""""/    '.  (__/||             (_))__(_))--(__))
                      \::).-'  -._  \/ \\/\|
              __ _ .-'`)/  '-'. . '. |  (i_O
          .-'      \       -'      '\|
     _ _./      .-'|       '.  (    \\                           % % %
  .-'   :      '_  \         '-'\  /|/      @ @ @               % % % %
 /      )\_      '- )_________.-|_/^\      @ @ @@@             % %\/% %
 (   .-'   )-._-:  /        \(/\'-._ `.     @|@@@@@              ..|........
  (   )  _//_/|:  /          `\()   `\_\     |/_@@               )'-._.-._.-
   ( (   \()^_/)_/             )/      \\    /                  /   /
    )  _.-\\.\(_)__._.-'-.-'-.//_.-'-.-.)\-'/._                /       
.-.-.-'   _o\ \\\     '::'   (o_ '-.-' |__\'-.-;~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~~/   /\   
          \ /  \\\__          )_\    .:::::::.-'\            '- - -|
     :::''':::::^)__\:::::::::::::::::'''''''-.  \                  '- - - - 
    :::::::  '''''''''''   ''''''''''''':::. -'\  \                    
_____':::::_____________________________________\__\_________________________
--
```

We can also surmise that the artist was associated with [Arizona State University](https://www.asu.edu/) in 1996 and was a [Snoopy fan](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/rec.arts.ascii/TmHZlMR6nF8/CKUHV7O9tIoJ).

Answer (score 19):

The picture is a classic piece of ASCII art published on several ASCII art sites, most importantly [all the way back on GeoCities](http://www.oocities.org/spunk1111/favorite.htm#swansiger), the site that inspired the time machine look.

Who exactly C. Swansiger *is* is perhaps lost in time; the author signed their work but no present-day source includes a link to further details. It probably doesn’t really matter, it isn’t anyone connected with Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

Ah, you refer to the ascii art in the sourcecode of this site while "time traveling" (lines 92-113).

I think, the artist is indeed "C.Swansiger", as shown in the picture and as stated at the site https://www.asciiart.eu/mythology/unicorns from which the ascii art was probably copied. I am not sure if he/she would appreciate it if we tried to further dig up his/her identity ;)

Unicorns rule! ;)